# C# Alternative To Generic Datatable

Tags: c#, oop, datatable

Please see the following:

```
public static DataTable GetSqlDataTable(string connStr, string strSqlStatement)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter dA = new SqlDataAdapter();

    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        dA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(strSqlStatement, conn);
        dA.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        throw exc;
    }
}
```

How can I use an `object` instead of a generic data container to avoid these generic data tables?

Comment: either do the mapping manually from the DataTable or use entity framework

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper .

Comment: What is the point of `catch(Exception exc) { throw exc; }`? Also, both `DataTable` and `SqlDataAdapter` implement `IDisposable`, and should be initialized with `using` blocks.

Comment: And the SqlConnection is also IDisposable. Also note, when rethrowing an exception from within a catch block, if you *were* going to do it, just do `throw;` otherwise you will lose the stack trace from the exception. `throw exc;` is never correct.

Comment: Please don't `throw ex`; that removes the original exception details and [says the exception was thrown by your code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b29a539c-0286-47a5-97ed-2832700acb28/exception-does-not-include-stack-information-why?forum=csharpgeneral). Remove the entire `try` block from your code.

Comment: @Steve read up on the entity framework, super cool. I had never heard about that until today, is that widely used to avoid the task of writing data access code?

Comment: @MikeCMR it is widely used since. Not sure if its purely for the data access code part though.

Comment: @Steve again, thank you. Typically, my usage for the data tables has been, fill one with a sql command, and then use the data table so I can iterate through it, performing tasks based on reach row.  It seems EF will actually make this easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create the object:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then create the objects when you read the sql data:

```
private static IEnumerable<MyObj> ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
    {
        string queryString =
            "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

        using (SqlConnection connection =
                   new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // Call Read before accessing data.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               yield return ReadSingleRow((IDataRecord)reader);
            }

            // Call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    private static MyObj ReadSingleRow(IDataRecord record)
    {
        return new MyObj{ ID = record[0], Name = record[1]};
    }
```

Comment: At that point, you should consider using a DataReader. Creating and filling a datatable for this purpose would be wasteful from a performance and memory perspective.

Comment: Updated answer to be better suited to the question.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Is there any comments you can add that can explain what was just gained, though? (in comparison to the generic data table) I guess I should have added that to the question. Sorry!

Comment: For performance reasons, you wouldn't want to create a DataTable structure, fill it with data, and then just read from it into yet another set of structures. DataReader is a fast and efficient way of reading data as you only load into memory the data you are currently processing. As an added benefit, you skip the DataTable creation and population step which will load all of the data into memory before you can use it.

Comment: Using OOP principles also makes the code more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: The SqlCommand and SqlDataReader are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the reader, since it is closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block.

Comment: @ClaytonHarbich, two more quick clarifications. So really, I am wanting to get ID of 0 and name of 1 out of my 'SELECT' query results, and in this method, you are reading and processing as CPerson was saying? And that is where your performance is gained? And lastly, what if I wanted to iterate across every record in this table, could I create an obj to iterate on, or is that ruining any performance gains I was getting?

Comment: The best performance always will be in the Sql query. Second best is this that will look at each row as needed. Performance as a whole is very hard to talk about because the answer is always "It depends". This solution will always be preferred over the DataTable though.